# Changing the address to "self" object in python will not affect the object created for it

Tags: python, object, self

This code changes the address of self object to initial object address in init function from Subsequent initialization of object. But it actually creates new address for the object created. I understand scope of self is only during init function execution. My question is after init method finishes execution does it return anything?

---

```
class A:
 addr = None
 def __init__(self):
  if A.addr:
   print("Current object address:",id(self))
   print("First object address:",id(A.addr))
   self = A.addr
   print("Current object address after modification:",id(self))
  else:
   print("Initial address",id(self))
   A.addr = self

>>> a = A()
Initial address 2433753170104
>>> b = A()
Current object address: 2433753170216
First object address: 2433753170104
Current object address after modification: 2433753170104
>>> id(a),id(b)
(2433753170104, 2433753170216)
```

Comment: You're only changing what the identifier `self` refers to. You can't change the object on which `__init__` is running.

Comment: Doing `self=` only overrides `self` in that method. It doesn't actually change the object. If you want to actually edit how an object is created, you'll have to use the `__new__` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment -- if you want a constructor to always return the exact same instance (this is known as a singleton) use the `__new__` constructor like so:

```
class Singleton:
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance


s1 = Singleton()

s2 = Singleton()

s1 is s2  # --> True  (this is the same as id(s1) == id(s2))
```